# Best practice for applying new CSS classes to legacy data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

We are working on a legacy application and want to give it a new look. There are many `<input type="button" />`, `<input type="submit" />`, `<input type="reset" />`, etc. scattered throughout almost 200 JSP pages in our web application. None of them have a `class="something"` value set already.

We have found an interesting CSS which contains a new class definition which will style the aforementioned input types the way we want. I would like to apply these class definitions everywhere, however it seems wrong to me to have to go to each `<input>` and add `class="some_class"` to each individual element.

What is the best way to go about this? I could use jQuery and add include script to the top of the header page in do something like `$('input[type="submit"]').addClass("some_class")`. This minimizes the amount of code I need to modify, but is that the best way?
I am not familiar enough with CSS to know if it is possible to add a class dynamically using a selector - based on my reading it doesn't seem possible.

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I have tried this already in our 'default.css':

`input[type="submit"], input[type="reset", input[type="button"]{
    class : "someclass"
}`

But it doesn't work (I'm assuming class : "someclass" is not actually valid")

Comment: Are you wanting to style all of the inputs or just specific ones?

Comment: You haven't noticed that `input[type="submit"]` is css? [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @3rror404: all of them

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, but how do I add a class to those elements selected in the CSS?

Comment: if you want to add a class do it in jQuery - but you can just do what's in my answer and move your styles from "someclass" into that block

Comment: You don't need to, look at...uh...[Wirey's (?) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25981162/82548), it's a selector, it does the same thing as a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css attributes selector

```
input[type='submit'],input[type='button'],input[type='reset']{
      your css styles
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

W3C Specs

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: I understand that. Please see my edit above. It's the `your css styles` I don't understand. Can I just set a new style in that code block?

Comment: @YeeLikeKram yes copy your styles from the other class and put it inside the block

Comment: Ok. So there's no way to reference another class from my input selector in the CSS, then. Alright. Or use jQuery. Think I'm getting it now.